# Localize value giving error in actionlink in .cshtml

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, localization

```
<h4> @Html.ActionLink(Localizer["India"], "Index", "Home")</h4>
```

The above gives an error stating that "there is no formal parameter corresponding..." in the actionlink

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink(Localizer["India"].Value, "Index", "Home")